# $G$ be a finite simple group , then every element of $G$ can be written as a product of $n$-th powers of elements of $G$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

Let $G$ be a finite simple group , let $n$ be a positive integer such that not all $n$-th powers of elements of $G$ are identity , then is it true that every element of $G$ can be written as  a product of $n$-th powers of elements of $G$ ?

Comment: That's true for any finite group. It doesn't need to be simple. Also every element $g$ is itself an $n$-th power of some power of $g$. For a simple group, you don't even need $\gcd(n,|G|)=1$. You just need to assume that not all $n$-th powers are trivial.

Comment: @DerekHolt : Yes , I realized that the simplicity is not needed if we assume the coprime condition , so avoiding the co-prim condition , for simple groups , could you please elaborate on your comment (as I have edited accordingly ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following steps reach the destination.

1. The subgroup generated by the $n$th powers is non-trivial because there are non-trivial $n$th powers.
2. The conjugate of an $n$th power is another $n$th power.
3. The same holds for any product of $n$th powers, so the group generated by the $n$th powers is normal, and hence all of $G$

Comment: I couldn't find a duplicate (the buzzwords *generated*+*power* gave 150 hits, but no matches to this question), but something tells me this has been handled on our site earlier. If you find a good original, @-ping me, please, so I can take appropriate measures.